# How can i export a ggplot graph in Excel with writexl package in R?

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2

i have a data frame in R :

```
library(tidyverse)
a = rnorm(10)
b = runif(10)
var = c(rep("chair",5),rep("table",5)  )
d = tibble(a,b,var);d
```

and a graph :

```
p2 = ggplot(data = d, aes(x=var, y=a)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=a),outlier.shape=NA)+
  facet_wrap( ~ var, scales="free")+
  ggtitle("boxs") ;p2
```

now i want to export the data frame in a xlsx file in one sheet and in the same sheet or in a different sheet to export the ggplot graph with the use of writexl package in R.

For the data frame the tasj is easily implemented with :

```
writexl::write_xlsx(list(d),
                    path = paste("path\\name_file.xlsx"))
```

but i don't know under the writexl package this can be done for the graph.

Any help ?

Comment: You want to export plot output to an Excel file? I think you will need to first plot to a file device like `help("png")`, see `help("ggsave")`. I don't know if there are packages that would then allow you to use R to import the plot from the file into Excel but writexl certainly doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBMK this is not possible using `writexl`. But using the `openxlsx` package you could export a ggplot via `openxlsx::insertPlot`. One remark: `insertPlot` will export the current (printed) plot. That's why I added the `print(p2)`:

```r
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Data")
addWorksheet(wb, "Plot")

writeData(wb, "Data", d)
print(p2)
insertPlot(wb, "Plot")

saveWorkbook(wb, "plot.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

**UPDATE** In case you want to export multiple datasets and plots you could put the code inside a function and use a loop:

Note: For simplicity I duplicated your data and plot.

```
dlist <- list(d, d)
plist <- list(p2, p2)

library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()

export_xl <- function(i) {
  data_sheet <- paste("Data", i)
  plot_sheet <- paste("Plot", i)
  addWorksheet(wb, data_sheet)
  addWorksheet(wb, plot_sheet)
  
  writeData(wb, data_sheet, dlist[[i]])
  print(plist[[i]])
  insertPlot(wb, plot_sheet)
}

for (i in seq(2)) {
  export_xl(i)
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "plot.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: additional question: if a had a list of data frames and a list of graphs,can export them all in one excel file in different sheets ? And how? Assume d1,d2,d3 differents data frames and p1,p2,p3 differents plots.So i must export them in 6 different sheets in a first case and in a second case to combine data frame with plot in one sheet respectively, i.e d1 with p1 in the same sheet, d2 with p2 and d3 with p3.What modifications must be done in the code in your answer ?

Comment: See my update. BTW: Of course could you add the data and the plot on the same sheet, e.g. you could add the `startCol` and `startRow` where you want to insert your plot.