# How can i insert data frames ang ggplots with different number of data frames and plots in R?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

i have two data frames df1 and df2.Also i have 5 different graphs and i want to insert them in different sheets in excel file.

Similarly to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74373120/how-can-i-export-a-ggplot-graph-in-excel-with-writexl-package-in-r/74373312?noredirect=1#comment131297947_74373312) i have

```
data_list = list(DF1,DF2)
graph_list = list(G1,G2,G3,G4,G5)

BOOK  = createWorkbook()

export_xl = function(i) {
  data_sheet  =  paste("Data_Frame", i)
  plot_sheet  =  paste("Graph", i)
  addWorksheet(BOOK, data_sheet)
  addWorksheet(BOOK, plot_sheet)
  
  writeData(BOOK, data_sheet, data_list[[i]])
  print(graph_list[[i]])
  insertPlot(BOOK, plot_sheet,width = 5,height = 5)
}

for (i in seq(length(graph_list))) {
  export_xl(i)
}

saveWorkbook(BOOK,path.xlsx,overwrite=TRUE)
```

but it exports the two data frames and only the first two graphs ?

How can i correct this to exposrt all dfs nad graphs in different sheets in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the export function into two, one for the data, one for the plots. Then use two `for` loops:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

data_list <- list(mtcars, iris)
graph_list <- list(p, p, p, p, p)

BOOK <- createWorkbook()

export_data <- function(i) {
  data_sheet <- paste("Data_Frame", i)
  addWorksheet(BOOK, data_sheet)
  writeData(BOOK, data_sheet, data_list[[i]])
}

export_plot <- function(i) {
  plot_sheet <- paste("Graph", i)
  addWorksheet(BOOK, plot_sheet)
  print(graph_list[[i]])
  insertPlot(BOOK, plot_sheet, width = 5, height = 5)
}


for (i in seq_along(data_list)) {
  export_data(i)
}

for (i in seq_along(graph_list)) {
  export_plot(i)
}

saveWorkbook(BOOK, "plot.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much.That will do the job.